# What special character format does the ::before selectors content property accept?

Tags: css, sass

I need to insert a special character into the `::before` or `::after` selectors `content` property. What format do I need to write it in?

```
div::before {
  content: '→'
}
```

Comment: You can write that as-is.  Just save as UTF8.

Comment: Interesting. I'm compiling SCSS and that is not rendering.

Comment: You can also try `content: '\2192';`.

Comment: I'm using `grunt-contrib-sass` to compile the SCSS. But it's rendering incorrectly.

Comment: `content: '\2192';` worked. What tool do you use to find the correct code?

Comment: @etoxin A Unicode table.

Comment: http://unicode-table.com/en/ - here you go! :)